# Error response from daemon: failed to prune build cache: write /var/lib/docker/buildkit/containerdmeta.db: read-only file system

Tags: docker, windows-10

I had a problem with my docker...

docker system prune

```
d:\Documents\Udemy\DevOps                             
λ docker system prune                                                                                                            
WARNING! This will remove:                                                                                                       
  - all stopped containers                                                                                                       
  - all networks not used by at least one container                                                                              
  - all dangling images                                                                                                          
  - all dangling build cache                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                 
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y                                                                                       
Error response from daemon: failed to prune build cache: write /var/lib/docker/buildkit/containerdmeta.db: read-only file system 
                                                                                                                                 
d:\Documents\Udemy\DevOps
```

docker system prune

```
d:\Documents\Udemy\DevOps                             
λ docker system prune                                                                                                            
WARNING! This will remove:                                                                                                       
  - all stopped containers                                                                                                       
  - all networks not used by at least one container                                                                              
  - all dangling images                                                                                                          
  - all dangling build cache                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                 
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y                                                                                       
Error response from daemon: failed to prune build cache: write /var/lib/docker/buildkit/containerdmeta.db: read-only file system 
                                                                                                                                 
d:\Documents\Udemy\DevOps
λ
```

Here my Docker Version

```
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | select DisplayName,DisplayVersion | where {$_.DisplayName -like "Docker*"}

DisplayName    DisplayVersion
-----------    --------------
Docker Desktop 3.3.3


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Using `docker version`

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.14
 Version:           20.10.6
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.3
 Git commit:        370c289
 Built:             Fri Apr  9 22:49:36 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.6
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       8728dd2
  Built:            Fri Apr  9 22:44:56 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
  GitCommit:        05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
  GitCommit:        12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

**How solve it?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at this and [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758402/dockerfile-executor-failed-running-error-creating-overlay-mount-to-too-many-l) you might need to use one of the "reset" options in Docker Desktop; it seems like your Docker's internal state might have gotten corrupted in some way.

Answer (score 10):

Check that you have free space on your hard drive

Answer (score -4):

this is due to not having right permissions for your docker user group,
run usermod -aG docker $USER

Comment: This is incorrect. Happens even for the root user.