# running DockerFile of spring app is not working on windows

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-desktop

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILES=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILES} app.jar
EXPOSE 9099
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

when running the commande docker build . inside the directoery of the project i got this error :

[image]

Comment: There's a similar question already on SO.  Maybe it will help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67757905/error-response-from-daemon-failed-to-prune-build-cache-write-var-lib-docker-b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Could be due to insufficient space (refer : https://forums.docker.com/t/error-read-only-file-system-write-var-lib-docker-buildkit-metadata-v2-db/103637)
2. Might be Dockerfile name issue  (Dockerfile not dockerfile)

Comment: fixed after restart docker .